# PL/SQL local collection types not allowed in sql satements

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I got this error (PLS-00642) when trying to compile a compound trigger. I just learned about types and collections so it is still very confusing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_trecho_teste
FOR DELETE OR UPDATE OF shape ON tr_eixo_lt_ope
COMPOUND TRIGGER
   -- Declarative Section (optional)
   -- Variables declared here have firing-statement duration.
     TYPE num_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
     trechos num_list;

     --Trechos :
     TYPE trechos_update IS VARRAY(2) OF sde.st_geometry; -- This will contain old/new or old/null of trechos  
     TYPE trecho_dict IS TABLE OF trechos_update INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; -- This is a dictionary of the above, with keys as the cod
     trechos_dict trecho_dict;

     --Lts :
     TYPE trechos_in_lt_to_update IS TABLE OF trechos_update; -- List of trechos above in specific LT
     TYPE lt_dict IS TABLE OF trechos_in_lt_to_update INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; -- Dictionary of the above
     lts_dict lt_dict;

     -- Auxiliar de iteração :
     elem trechos_in_lt_to_update;

     --Executed before each row change- :NEW, :OLD are available
     BEFORE EACH ROW IS
     BEGIN
        trechos.extend;
        IF UPDATING THEN
            trechos(trechos.COUNT) := :NEW.PK_CD_TR_LT_OPE;
            trechos_dict(:NEW.PK_CD_TR_LT_OPE) := trechos_update(:OLD.SHAPE, :NEW.SHAPE);
        ELSE
            trechos(trechos.COUNT) := :OLD.PK_CD_TR_LT_OPE;
            trechos_dict(:NEW.PK_CD_TR_LT_OPE) := trechos_update(:OLD.SHAPE, NULL);
        END IF;

     END BEFORE EACH ROW;

     --Executed aftereach row change- :NEW, :OLD are available
     AFTER EACH ROW IS
     BEGIN
       NULL;
     END AFTER EACH ROW;

     --Executed after DML statement
     AFTER STATEMENT IS
     BEGIN
        -- Construindo o dicionário com as lts e os seus trechos modificados
        FOR resultado IN (SELECT FK_CD_LT_OPE cod_lt,FK_CD_TR_LT_OPE cod_trecho FROM EIXO_LT_OPE_COM_TR_EIXO_LT_OPE WHERE FK_CD_TR_LT_OPE MEMBER OF trechos)
        LOOP
            IF lts_dict.EXISTS(resultado.cod_lt) THEN
                lts_dict(resultado.cod_lt).extend;
                lts_dict(resultado.cod_lt)(lts_dict(resultado.cod_lt).COUNT) := trechos_dict(cod_trecho);
            ELSE
                lts_dict(resultado.cod_lt) := trechos_in_lt_to_update(trechos_dict(cod_trecho));
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

       -- Iterando o dicionário construído acima
        elem := lts_dict.FIRST;
        WHILE elem IS NOT NULL LOOP
            elem := lts_dict.next(elem);
            cogeo_utils.rebuild_line('tr_eixo_lt_ope', elem, lts_dict(elem));
        END LOOP;
     END AFTER STATEMENT;
END trigger_trecho_teste;
```

The error occurs in the lines:

```
FOR resultado IN (SELECT FK_CD_LT_OPE cod_lt,FK_CD_TR_LT_OPE cod_trecho FROM EIXO_LT_OPE_COM_TR_EIXO_LT_OPE WHERE FK_CD_TR_LT_OPE MEMBER OF trechos)
LOOP
  IF lts_dict.EXISTS(resultado.cod_lt) THEN
    lts_dict(resultado.cod_lt).extend;
    lts_dict(resultado.cod_lt)(lts_dict(resultado.cod_lt).COUNT) := trechos_dict(cod_trecho);
  ELSE
    lts_dict(resultado.cod_lt) := trechos_in_lt_to_update(trechos_dict(cod_trecho));
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Is it because I'm accessing the collections inside the select loop? Is there a simple workaround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 11g you cannot use collection types declared in PL/SQL in the SQL scope. You need to create them in the SQL scope.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE num_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

and remove the type declaration from the trigger.

Comment: So that goes for all the types I've created? Or only this one in the select

Comment: You are using the other collections in the PL/SQL scope; the `trechos` collection is the only one that is used in the SQL statement and needs modifying (as far as I can see).